# Flask login redirect generates 302 but browser doesn't update like in other fucntions

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask

I am implementing a login fucntion for my webapp. For some reason the redirect isn't being implemented by the client/browser when sent through my login function. however it works just fine when i redirect with my logout function. I literally just copied the code from here https://realpython.com/using-flask-login-for-user-management-with-flask/

I have been reading some post since monday and they all point to having to do window.location.replace() however i am not very family with JS or JQUERY so am not sure exactly how that would be implemented to sync with my login fucntion.

```
@app.route("/login/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    print("current user is:{}".format(current_user))
    data_dict = config.DATA
    form = CredentialForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        db.session.commit()
        user = db.session.query(User).filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
        if user:
            if user.password == form.password.data:
                user.authenticated = True
                db.session.add(user)
                db.session.commit()
                login_user(user, remember=True)
                print("current user is:{}".format(current_user))
                return redirect(request.args.get("next") or url_for('dashboard'))

    return  render_template('login.html',intial_data=data_dict,form=form)
```

Comment: I just wanted to add that, I have gone through a lot of tutorials for implementing login with flask and i haven't seen any extra js code being added for redirect so wondering why my case is an exception if that's the solution

Comment: why `db.session.commit()` after `if form.validate_on_submit():` ?

Comment: probably just lagacy from a previous version of me doing somthing i was up super late (5am) trying to figure it out and a little loopy... this however isn't the cause of the issue.. before i even started using a db i was expierencing with simple user class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you send your request in ajax, when you get a response if `response.redirected` is **true**, you can use `window.location.reload()` that reload the web page. For example using **fetch** for ajax request

```
fetch("/login", {
      method:"POST",
      headers: new Headers(),
      body: ...
}).then( (response) => {
       /*
         if redirect is true new url is ready underthehood, reload the page will trigger new route.
       */
       if(response.redirected) window.location.reload();
       ...
}).catch( (error) => console.error("[-] Error with the request"));
```

[fetch api documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)